# программы не используют xdg-open для запуска

Tags: linux, archlinux, xorg

Захотелось изменить стандартный файловый менеджер для запуска окон и столкнулся с проблемой того, что не используются ассоции из **mimeapps.list**, хотя сам **xdg-open** работает как нужно.
В чем может быть проблема?
Приложил скрин с дефолтным менеджером в случае браузера(firefox). Для telegram-а, например, он другой. Вот сам mimeapps.list

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/tg=userapp-Telegram Desktop-JM94A1.desktop
inode/directory=ranger.desktop

[Added Associations]
x-scheme-handler/tg=userapp-Telegram Desktop-JM94A1.desktop;
inode/directory=ranger.desktop
```

Ссылочка в ***.local/share/applications/*** имеется
[image: дефолтный менеджер для firefox]

Comment: на скрине же вроде не ФМ, а диалог открытия файла, не?

Comment: Да. Это диалог открытия для ФМ. Я все же не ошибся в описании к проблеме. И мне нужно его поменять и сделать общим для всех программ которые используется, хотя бы для тех, с которыми я часто сталкиваются при работе. Или это невозможно?

Comment: Если кратко, то диалог открытия, вообще говоря, является частью приложения, не связан с ФМ'ом и не обязательно может быть изменяем… что до двух основных гуёвых фреймворков, то в Qt он обычно привязан к [движку отображения интерфейса](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#Theme_engines), в старых версиях gtk он обычно не изменяем (если не считать хака с `LD_PRELOAD`), а в более свежих, по идее, можно [задать](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#Consistent_file_dialog) с помощью `xdg-desktop-portal` (сам я его не щупал)